# MongoDB Aggregation - Can't join two collections

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

I have a product collection and a brand collection, so each product has a brand, so I want to get each product with its own brand values.

products collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64d944cbc32ec6fcc466de27"),
    "name" : "Producto 1",
    "description" : "undefined",
    "brandId" : "64d41c4983026a2b65df8479",
    "showroomId" : "64bb07419a44219522c6b63d",
    "price" : "100",
    "quantity" : "5",
    "isForRent" : "false",
    "additionalCost" : null,
    "size" : "N/A",
    "color" : "Blanco",
    "brand" : "marca1",
    "comments" : "undefined",
    "createdOn" : 1691960523001.0,
    "productImage" : "productPhoto-1691960523078.jpeg"
}
```

brands collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64d41c4983026a2b65df8479"),
    "name" : "Petit Prata",
    "emailId" : "email@gmail.com",
    "password" : null,
    "lastLogin" : null,
    "responsablePerson" : "John Smith",
    "subscription" : null,
    "address" : "calle 10, 13",
    "phoneNo" : "1234567890",
    "profileImage" : "brandPhoto-1691622473114.jpeg",
    "slogan" : "tttt",
    "rol" : "VIEWER",
    "createdDate" : 1691622473028.0,
    "updatedDate" : 1691622473028.0,
    "celPhone" : null,
    "dayOfpay" : "none",
    "isActive" : true,
    "showroomId" : "64bb07419a44219522c6b63d",
    "comments" : "yeeaahhh\nbienric\nwqev\ne",
    "mailSchedule" : "30",
    "facebook" : "facebook",
    "twitter" : "erht"
}
```

My aggregation query:

```
aggregates = [
   {
     $lookup: {
       from: "brands",
       localField: "brandId",
       foreignField: "_id",
       as: "brandData"
     }
   }
]
```

Expected Result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64d944cbc32ec6fcc466de27"),
    "name" : "Producto 1",
    "description" : "undefined",
    "brandId" : "64d41c4983026a2b65df8479",
    "showroomId" : "64bb07419a44219522c6b63d",
    "price" : "100",
    "quantity" : "5",
    "isForRent" : "false",
    "additionalCost" : null,
    "size" : "N/A",
    "color" : "Blanco",
    "brand" : "marca1",
    "comments" : "undefined",
    "createdOn" : 1691960523001.0,
    "productImage" : "productPhoto-1691960523078.jpeg"
    "brandData": [{
        "_id" : ObjectId("64d41c4983026a2b65df8479"),
        "name" : "Petit Prata",
        "emailId" : "email@gmail.com",
        "password" : null,
        "lastLogin" : null,
        "responsablePerson" : "John Smith",
        "subscription" : null,
        "address" : "calle 10, 13",
        "phoneNo" : "1234567890",
        "profileImage" : "brandPhoto-1691622473114.jpeg",
        "slogan" : "tttt",
        "rol" : "VIEWER",
        "createdDate" : 1691622473028.0,
        "updatedDate" : 1691622473028.0,
        "celPhone" : null,
        "dayOfpay" : "none",
        "isActive" : true,
        "showroomId" : "64bb07419a44219522c6b63d",
        "comments" : "yeeaahhh\nbienric\nwqev\ne",
        "mailSchedule" : "30",
        "facebook" : "facebook",
        "twitter" : "erht"
      }]
}
```

As you can see, the related field is `brandId`, but I got an empty array for the `brandData` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As the `brandId` in the `products` collection is a string type which unmatches the type for the `_id` field in the `brand` collection.

You should convert the `brandId` to the ObjectId type and compare

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "brands",
      let: {
        brandId: {
          $toObjectId: "$brandId"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$brandId"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "brandData"
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fuXV6k17jRE)

Reference: [Join Conditions and Subqueries on a Joined Collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection)